# Reload width ajax and keep the current class

Tags: ajax, jquery, reload

I have an issue about ajax.

make an example: I have a menu list (ul li) and by default the first one has class 'current'.
if I click the second item assign class 'current' to him with jquery and remove it from the previous one.

Now, I need reload the menu list with ajax, so I call the ajax function that calls a php function that return an update html list.

But in this way I lose the 'current' class from the second list, that before I assigned with jquery.

Happens to me many times to have this type of problems.. What is the correct solution to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing it is to get the index of the `li` with the class `current` and in the `ajax` success callback assign the `current` class to the appropriate index

look at this fiddle to get the index of the `li` http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/zyayj/

in your `success` callback

```
success:function(data){
var i = index -1; // index is zero based and eq() is 1 based
$("ul li:eq(i)").addClass("current");

}
```

Comment: ok, but if with the php function I added a item? the last index is no longer valid... Now I use the id for every item, before call the ajax function I saved the current item in a variable and when ajax is complete I restore the 'current'..but I don't think that this solution is the "correct solution".
Maybe with the session...

Answer (score 0):

I think your question indicates that you don't already know that web pages are "stateless", meaning that they do not "automatically" hold or store anything that you do with them.

Please see my answer ho a privious question which summarizes the ways to deal with retaining the state of things - the principles would remain the same for your menus.

[Stateless HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365962/editable-form-and-save-changes/6369456#6369456)